# Protecting group policy

Tags: group-policy

I want to protect my group policy, but I don't have any idea about how to do that. Is there anybody who can help?

I want to create a policy to disable certain groups from editing defined policies, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

By default your GPO is protected from being edited by your users. The default permissions are:

[image: GPO default settings]

Now if you need to prevent the GPO from being edited by other admins, you need to evoke that security group, but make sure you add yourself the permissions, otherwise you can't modify going forward.

To read more look at: [GPO delegation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781991%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)